# Include ip address of node in Chef InSpec test

Tags: testing, chef-infra

I'm running InSpec tests through Test Kitchen

My InSpec test shall ensure, that the output of a curl command is "HelloWorld!"

The following code-block works as desired:

```
describe command("curl localhost}") do
    its('stdout') { should match /HelloWorld!/ }
end
```

**Question**

How can I include a nodes attribute (ip address) inside my curl test?

In .erb-templates I can use `<%= node['ipaddress'] %>`

The following approch isn't working

```
describe command("curl #{:ipaddress}") do
    its('stdout') { should match /HelloWorld!/ }
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not specifically supported. InSpec is totally separate from Chef and has no knowledge of Chef and Ohai stuff. You would probably want to make a little implementation yourself, but check the `os` helper in InSpec.